# Trouble in plotting a candlestick chart plotly javascript

Tags: javascript, plotly

I am new at HTML and JAVASCRIPT, I am trying to plot a candlestick chart, loading data from python, send it to javascript trough eel module. the picture shows the console.log of [data] required to plot. the plot doesn't show. when i set X close high low open manually it works.
can any one show me wath's wrong?

[console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZKIa.png)

```
var X = [];
var Op = [];
var Hi = [];
var Lo = [];
var Clo = [];
rows = eel.test("SOLUSDT", "1w")();
rows.then(value => value.map(function(row) {
                X.push(new Date(row[0]))}));
rows.then(value => value.map(function(row) {
                Op.push(parseFloat(row[1]))}));
rows.then(value => value.map(function(row) {
                Hi.push(parseFloat(row[2]))}));
rows.then(value => value.map(function(row) {
                Lo.push(parseFloat(row[3]))}));
rows.then(value => value.map(function(row) {
                Clo.push(parseFloat(row[4]))}));
var trace = {
              //x: X,
              close: Clo,
              high: Hi,
              low: Lo,
              open: Op,


              // cutomise colors
              increasing: {line: {color: 'black'}},
              decreasing: {line: {color: 'red'}},

              type: 'candlestick',
              xaxis: 'x',
              yaxis: 'y'
            };


 var data = [trace];
            console.log(data)

            var layout = {
              dragmode: 'zoom',
              showlegend: false,
              xaxis: {
                rangeslider: {
                     visible: true
                 }
              }
            };

   Plotly.newPlot('athrjy', data, layout);
```

Comment: No one will be able to help you without your code.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and be included in your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Here is the code

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from here, but still can't find out the solution.
I can't access array's elements. console.log(relay[0]) outputs "undifined".
the picture shows the console.

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2HWO.png)

```
var i = 0
rows.then(value => value.map(function(row) {
                relay[i] = parseFloat(row[4]);
                console.log(relay[i])
                i +=1;
              }));

console.log(relay[0])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).